# Using multiple occurrences of the same custom function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a custom function with the goal of performing multiplications of multiple arrays containing complex numbers in Excel. As an example, I have these 3 arrays defined on my Excel worksheet:

```
MATZ1:
0.99995021721684+0.0172827928509254i    -0.040624595514759-0.000234038263707613i
0.00490168593281832-0.850839538828158i  0.99995021721684+0.0172827928509254i

MATZ2:
 0.996262283629251+0.149720806155247i   -0.952677113437938-0.0475875415517989i
0.0156809592632005-0.313924412139317i   0.996262283629251+0.149720806155247i

MATZ3:
  0.998558978121825+0.0929765994909912i -0.128534373384092-0.00398493017536902i
0.0448308688243513-1.44602474297277i    0.998558978121825+0.0929765994909912i
```

And I have written the following function in VBA:

```
Function IMATMULT(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim l As Integer

    Dim temp As String

    Dim NumColumns As Variant
    Dim NumRows As Variant
    Dim NumRows2 As Variant

    NumRows = rng1.Rows.Count - 1
    NumColumns = rng2.Columns.Count - 1

    If (rng1.Columns.Count = rng2.Rows.Count) Then        
        NumRows2 = rng1.Columns.Count    
    Else    
        IMATMULT = "non compatible arrays"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim matrix() As String
    ReDim matrix(NumRows, NumColumns)

    For i = 0 To NumRows
        For j = 0 To NumColumns
            temp = "0"
            For l = 1 To NumRows2  
                temp = WorksheetFunction.ImSum(temp, WorksheetFunction.ImProduct(rng1(i + 1, l).Value, rng2(l, j + 1).Value))
            Next l

            matrix(i, j) = temp
        Next j
    Next i

    IMATMULT = matrix()
End Function
```

Which is able to multiply two complex arrays together. When I write the folowing code line in Excel, I get the correct result:

[image]

However, when I try to multiply more than two arrays, I get an error result:

[image]

I know I could just simply do the multiplication one array at a time, but I'd like to know why using my function twice doesn't work, as my current knowledge of VBA doesn't allow me to understand the reason for it.

Many thanks.

EDIT1:

It would seem the problem is that the output from this function is a different format than the input. To work as I need it, this function needs to accept an array of text as input. However, I have no idea how to pass such an array into a function, any help would be welcome.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that your function specifies both parameters to be ranges and its output is a string array?

Comment: Could it be that you are attempting to pass a range to the function but in certain scenarios, your function returns a string (I,e, `non compatible arrays`). If your internal call returns that, you outer call will get a string instead of a range

Comment: Note that all your row counting variables should neither be `Integer` nor `Variant` but `Long`. • Debug your function by creating a test sub calling the function: `Result = IMATMULT(Range("MATZ1"), Range("MATZ2"))` and go through it step by step using F8 to find out what is going on.

Comment: The function worked fine with only 2 arrays. I guess the problem is as described by @Zac. This means I must find a way to pass arays into the function instead of ranges

Comment: FYI - I see you use R. Matrix multiplication can easily be done with it!

Comment: @Parfait: Indeed, but I need to integrate these functions in an autmatic Excel tool, so R is out of the question.